# I want to use Loading Image on laoding partial view MVC 4?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

my issue is my partial view has a grid which has large data which takes time...now i want to use loading image like beforesend only to load my partial view...
my master data loaded quickly but my detail data in partial view takes time

here its my ajax ...

```html
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("get_Laptop_Detail_By_PO", "ChangeLaptopStage")',
                data: { PO_Number: PO_Number },
               
                beforeSend: function () {

                    $('.loader').show();
                    $('.main_area').addClass("disable_main_area");


                },
              
                success: function (data) {

              var Qty = data.ItemQuantity
              var Po_ID = data.PO_ID


              $("#Total_laptop_Qty").val(Qty)
              $("#PO_ID").val(Po_ID)

              




///This statement fetch my detail data in partial view ...i want to load this statement on loading image 

$("#LaptopDetail").load('@(Url.Action("Laptop_detail_By_PO", "ChangeLaptopStage", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?PO_Number=' + PO_Number);

                },
            });


<div id="LaptopDetail">
  
</div>
```

This is my controller where partial view calls

```html
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Laptop_detail_By_PO(string PO_Number, ChangeLaptop_Stage REC)
        {

            Cls_Lot Lot_cls = new Cls_Lot();
            List<LapTopDetail> LaptopDetail = new List<LapTopDetail>();

            ds = new DataSet();
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt2 = new DataTable();

            if (PO_Number != null)
            {
                ds = Lot_cls.getLaptopDetail_By_PO(22, PO_Number);

                dt = ds.Tables[1];


                foreach (DataRow drData in dt.Rows)
                {
                    LaptopDetail.Add(new LapTopDetail
                    {
                        //RowNumber = Convert.ToInt32(drData["RowNumber"]),
                        PO_Dtl_ID = Convert.ToInt32(drData["ID"]),
                        PO_mstr_ID = Convert.ToInt32(drData["LapTop_Master_ID"]),
                        WareHouseStatus = drData["WareHouseStatus"].ToString(),
                        GulfITBarcode = drData["GulfITBarcode"].ToString(),
                        Item_Orgainal_srNO = drData["Item_Orgainal_srNO"].ToString(),
                        Category = drData["Category"].ToString(),
                        Make_Brand = drData["Make_Brand"].ToString(),
                        Series = drData["Series"].ToString(),
                        ModelNO = drData["ModelNO"].ToString(),
                        Color = drData["Color"].ToString(),
                        Processor_Brand = drData["Processor_Brand"].ToString(),
                        Processor_Type = drData["Processor_Type"].ToString(),
                        Processor = drData["Processor"].ToString(),
                        Speed_GHZ = drData["Speed_GHZ"].ToString(),
                        Memmory_MB = drData["Memmory_MB"].ToString(),
                        Memmory_Type = drData["Memmory_Type"].ToString(),
                        LCD_Screen_Size_inchs = drData["LCD_Screen_Size_inchs"].ToString(),
                        Touch_Screen = drData["Touch_Screen"].ToString(),
                        LCD_Teatures = drData["LCD_Teatures"].ToString(),
                        HDD_1_GB = drData["HDD_1_GB"].ToString(),
                        HDD_1_Type = drData["HDD_1_Type"].ToString(),
                        HDD_2_GB = drData["HDD_2_GB"].ToString(),
                        HDD_2_Type = drData["HDD_2_Type"].ToString(),
                        Graphic_Card_Name = drData["Graphic_Card_Name"].ToString(),
                        Graphic_Card_Memory_MB = drData["Graphic_Card_Memory_MB"].ToString(),
                        Camera = drData["Camera"].ToString(),
                        Camera_MegaPixel = drData["Camera_MegaPixel"].ToString(),
                        Lan = drData["Lan"].ToString(),
                        Wifi = drData["Wifi"].ToString(),
                        Bluetooth = drData["Bluetooth"].ToString(),
                        NFC = drData["NFC"].ToString(),
                        OpticalDriver = drData["OpticalDriver"].ToString(),
                        OpticalDriver_Type = drData["OpticalDriver_Type"].ToString(),
                        USB_Ports_Qty = drData["USB_Ports_Qty"].ToString(),
                        SD_Card_Reader = drData["SD_Card_Reader"].ToString(),
                        Stylus_Pen = drData["Stylus_Pen"].ToString(),
                        Finger_Printer_Reader = drData["Finger_Printer_Reader"].ToString(),
                        HDMI = drData["HDMI"].ToString(),
                        VGA = drData["VGA"].ToString(),
                        Display_Port = drData["Display_Port"].ToString(),
                        Thunderbolt = drData["Thunderbolt"].ToString(),
                        Audio_Port_Mic = drData["Audio_Port_Mic"].ToString(),
                        Audio_Port_Sound = drData["Audio_Port_Sound"].ToString(),
                        Speakers = drData["Speakers"].ToString(),
                        Battery = drData["Battery"].ToString(),
                        Ext_Adapter = drData["Ext_Adapter"].ToString(),
                        Other_1 = drData["Other_1"].ToString(),
                        Other_2 = drData["Other_2"].ToString(),
                        Other_3 = drData["Other_3"].ToString(),
                        Other_4 = drData["Other_4"].ToString(),

                    });
                }


                REC.Laptop_Detail = LaptopDetail;

                return PartialView("Laptop_detail", REC);
            }


            else
            {
                return PartialView("P_Error");

            }

        }
```

Please help me

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: my question is simple..i want to load my partial view on loading image image.gif ..so that user wait untill its load completly

Comment: So what problems are you having and what is not working with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it on global **[`$(document).ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)** and **[`$(document).ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)** `events`  to attach it globally for all the request. There is an option called `global` in `$.ajax` which when set to `false` will not take **global events** into consideration.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
      $('.loader').toggle();
      $('.main_area').toggleClass("disable_main_area");
}).ajaxComplete(function(){
      $('.loader').toggle();
      $('.main_area').toggleClass("disable_main_area");
});
```

As I said this will attach it to all `ajax request` and if you want it not appear for all the `ajax requests` then add that `global:false` in each `ajax request` like on below:

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   global:false,
   ...
});
```

For more `global` events visit - **[Global Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)**

Now if you want to attach it to only particular `.load` you can try as below:

```
$('.loader').show(); //show it before calling load
$("#LaptopDetail").load('@(Url.Action("Laptop_detail_By_PO", "ChangeLaptopStage", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?PO_Number=' + PO_Number), function() {
    $('.loader').hide(); //hide once load completes
});
```